# Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc() What Gives?

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to display users from the database on the page after login but i keep getting an error message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc()

here is the code:

```
    <?php
session_start(); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
<div class="body content">

    <div class="welcome">
        <div class="alert alert-success"><?= $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>
        <img src="<?= $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>"><br />
        Welcome <span class="user"><?= $_SESSION['username'] ?></span>

        <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database");
        //Select queries return a resultset
        $sql = "SELECT username, avatar FROM users";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql); //$result = mysqli_result object
        //var_dump($result);
        ?>

        <div id='registered'>
        <span>All registered users:</span>

        <?php
        //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ //returns associative array of fetched row
         while($row = fetch_assoc($result)){ //returns associative array of fetched row
            //echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($row);
            //echo '</pre>';
            echo "<div class='userlist'><span>$row[username]</span>";
            echo "<img src='$row[avatar]'></div>";
        }
        ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fetch_assoc() isn't a function so that error message is correct. It's a method of the mysqli result object. You're missing the object part of the OOP.

Comment: Why did you comment the line with `$result->fetch_assoc()`? What error were you getting originally?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do this, you're mixing object oriented and procedural:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ //returns associative array of fetched row
            //echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($row);
            //echo '</pre>';
            echo "<div class='userlist'><span>$row[username]</span>";
            echo "<img src='$row[avatar]'></div>";
        }
```

Comment: i don't have mysqlnd installed on my server, so that code, which was was my original code, gives me an error too. Is there another way?

Comment: Switch the other stuff above to procedural then instead of mixing it

Comment: please provide example

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct script for procedural connection to database:

```
<?php    
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1");
    $sql = "SELECT username, avatar FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row["username"] . " " . $row["avatar"] . "<br>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: i get this error trying that code:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Are you copy my code, beacouse working without error on my phpMyAdmin. I'm trying to find why you have this error.

Comment: I found! You are not connected to the database. look at your first the row: $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1");

Comment: This your code is wrong: $sql = "SELECT username, avatar FROM users";  When I write username like username1, I have stricly error like you.

Comment: I created this example database named db1, the table named users, fields named id, username, avatar. You inspect your database names.